# Is there a way to ignore some machines (set to nothing) in job shop scheduling problem?

Tags: python, nan, pulp

I am working on a job scheduling program with the objective of reducing makespan that involves scheduling multiple jobs on multiple machines, where:

1. The same job cannot operate on different machines at the same time
2. Only one job can process at a given time on a given machine

However, I'd like to add a constraint that some machines may not be needed to process a particular job. As shown below, for the list of machine elements, job 1 can occur on machine 0 and 2, but doesn't need to go through machine 1 (it can skip this machine). To designate the null, I added np.nan. **(Note: If you insert either 0, 1, or 2 here in place of np.nan, this entire code will run without errors.)**

Here is my code so far:

```
from pulp import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import collections as cl
from itertools import product

# define model
schedule = LpProblem(name="Minimize_Schedule", sense=LpMinimize)

# define number of machines (m) and jobs (n)
m = 3
n = 3

# for each job, the processing time of each
times = [[2, 1, 2],
         [1, 2, 2],
         [1, 2, 1]]

# for each job, the order the machines will go in
# for job 1, machine 1 is not needed
machines = [[0, np.nan, 2],
            [1, 2, 0],
            [2, 1, 0]]

# variables

# objective function to minimize (the makespan)
c = LpVariable(name="C")
# starting time x, on job j (from all jobs n) on machine i (from all machines m)
x = [[LpVariable(name='x({} ,{} )'.format(j+1, i+1), lowBound=0) for i in range(m)] for j in range(n)]
# y is a binary, where 1, if job j precedes job k on machine i; else 0
y = [[[LpVariable(name='y({} ,{} ,{} )'.format(j+1, k+1, i+1), cat="Binary") for i in range(m)] for k in range(n)] for j in range(n)]

# sum of total time for all machines (m) and jobs (n)
M = sum(times[i][j] for i in range(n) for j in range(m))

# add objective function to schedule model
schedule += c

# job j can only begin after job i has been completed
for (j, i) in product(range(n), range(1, m)):
    schedule += x[j][machines[j][i]] - x[j][machines[j][i-1]] >= times[j][machines[j][i-1]]

# same jobs cannot occur at same time
for (j, k) in product(range(n), range(n)):
    if k != j:
        for i in range(m):
            schedule += x[j][i] - x[k][i] + M*y[j][k][i] >= times[k][i]
            schedule += -x[j][i] + x[k][i] - M*y[j][k][i] >= times[j][i] - M
        
   
for j in range(n):
    schedule += c - x[j][machines[j][m-1]] >= times[j][machines[j][m-1]]

status = schedule.solve()

print(f"status: {schedule.status}, {LpStatus[schedule.status]}")
print("Completion time: ", schedule.objective.value())

for i,j in product(range(m),range(n)):
    if x[i][j].varValue >= 0:
        print("job %d starts on machine %d at time %g" % (i+1, j+1, x[i][j].varValue))
```

But I'm running into an error at this line:

```
# job j can only begin after job i has been completed
for (j, i) in product(range(n), range(1, m)):
    schedule += x[j][machines[j][i]] - x[j][machines[j][i-1]] >= times[j][machines[j][i-1]]
```

Which says:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float
```

Is it not possible to insert a missing value into the machine list for this type of Mixed Integer program? Or will a simple update to this line of code suffice?

As another attempt, I tried to add `None` instead of `np.nan` and this returned the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType
```

Comment: Your "code that runs without errors" is missing a definition of `x` ...  :)

Comment: Dang it :) Ok I just added them

Comment: Also...  Your model is not very readable.  You should either rename your variables or add some clear comments.  `c, x, y` ??...    # y[i,j,k] is the decision to i at time j on machine k... etc.

Comment: Hopefully that helps a bit. Been thinking about this problem in my head for awhile, so the variables stuck in my brain.. Also when I replace np.nan with None, it errors as "list indices must be slices or integers, not NoneType"... added this to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are a couple issues in your formulation (for the model without any excluded machines).  It runs/solves with a zero value for me, so I'm not sure what result your are getting.  But that is a separate issue.

If you want to "exclude" some machines within the context of some jobs, I think you need to do a bit more work on the indexing.  Specifically, if you were to write out "the math" for some constraints, you would be doing something like "for each job-machine pair *that exists in the plan* make some constraint..."  So, the way I would approach this is to build subsets (as needed) to only include valid starts.  An example below.  Note also, I like using the `LpVariaible.dicts` method to create vars.  I think it is cleaner, and then you can tuple-index them because they are held in a dictionary.

And lastly, some consistency in nomenclature will help readability!  You have `i,j,k,m,n` when I think you can probably tackle this with `j, j_prime, m, ...`

```
from pulp import *

# define number of machines (m) and jobs (j)
machines = 3
jobs = 2

# for each job, the order the machines will go in
# for job 1, machine 1 is not needed
machine_sequence = [[0, None, 2],
                    [1, 2, 0 ]]

valid_starts = [(j, m) for j in range(jobs) for m in range(machines)  if machine_sequence[j][m] != None]

model = LpProblem("Example", LpMinimize)

# Improved Variable...?  using LpVariable.dicts
s = LpVariable.dicts("start time", indexs=valid_starts, lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')

# starting time x, on job j (from all jobs n) on machine i (from all machines m)
x = [[LpVariable(name='x({} ,{} )'.format(j+1, i+1), lowBound=0) for i in range(machines)] for j in range(jobs)]

print(type(s), s)
print(type(x), x)

# random constraint for j-m pairs that are valid
for j, m in valid_starts:
    model += s[j, m] <= 10
```

#### Edit...  Partial model (1 constraint)

I tinkered a bit more with this.  Turns out with your data the way that you have it, it is easier to remove the "None" in the machine sequence, because you will need to iterate through that sequence.  Preserving it in the times works just to position the times in the right spot.  A different data structure (dictionaries) might lead to a different approach.

```
from pulp import *

# define model
schedule = LpProblem(name="Minimize_Schedule", sense=LpMinimize)

# define number of machines (m) and jobs (j)
machines = 3
jobs = 2

# for each job, the order the machines will go in
# for job 1, machine 1 is not needed
machine_sequence = [[0, 2],
                    [1, 2,    0 ]]

# for each job, the processing time of each
times = [[2, None, 3],
         [1, 4,    5]]

valid_starts = [(j, m) for j in range(jobs) for m in machine_sequence[j]]

# x[j, m] = start time for job j on machine m
x = LpVariable.dicts("start time", indexs=valid_starts, lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')

# machine sequence constraint 
# for each machine in the job sequence (except the 0th), the start time of the
# machine must be greater than the previous start + duration
for j in range(jobs):                  # for each job
    for m_idx in range(1, len(machine_sequence[j])):     # for each machine in job's seq, except 0
        # convenience for bookkeeping...  
        curr_machine = machine_sequence[j][m_idx]
        prior_machine = machine_sequence[j][m_idx - 1]

        # so,
        schedule += x[j, curr_machine] >= x[j, prior_machine] + times[j][prior_machine]

print(schedule)
```

#### Yields:

```
Minimize_Schedule:
MINIMIZE
None
SUBJECT TO
_C1: - start_time_(0,_0) + start_time_(0,_2) >= 2

_C2: - start_time_(1,_1) + start_time_(1,_2) >= 4

_C3: start_time_(1,_0) - start_time_(1,_2) >= 5

VARIABLES
start_time_(0,_0) Continuous
start_time_(0,_2) Continuous
start_time_(1,_0) Continuous
start_time_(1,_1) Continuous
start_time_(1,_2) Continuous
```

#### Edit #2...  A complete model

The below is a completed model that runs and (seems to) produce correct answers.

```
# makespan model for jobs with sequence of machine requirements
# that may exclude some machines

from pulp import *

# define model
schedule = LpProblem(name="Minimize_Schedule", sense=LpMinimize)

# define number of machines (m) and jobs (j)
machines = 3
jobs = 2

# for each job, the order the machines will go in
# for job 1, machine 1 is not needed
machine_sequence = [[0, 2],
                    [1, 2, 0 ]]

# for each job, the processing time on required machines
times = [[2, None, 3],
         [1, 4,    5]]
M=100
valid_starts = [(j, m) for j in range(jobs) for m in machine_sequence[j]]

# a convenience set that we will use later...  job-job'-machine combos
# for jobs that both compete for the same machine
jjm = [(j, j_prime, m)
        for j in range(jobs)
        for j_prime in range(jobs)
        for m in range(machines)
        if j != j_prime 
        and (j, m) in valid_starts
        and (j_prime, m) in valid_starts]

# x[j, m] = start time for job j on machine m
x = LpVariable.dicts("start time", indexs=valid_starts, lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
# y[j, j_prime, m] = indicator that job j precedes j_prime on machine m
y = LpVariable.dicts("precedence", indexs=jjm, cat='Binary')
# makespan variable to capture the longest makespan
c = LpVariable("makespan", lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')


####### machine sequence constraint #######
# for each machine in the job sequence (except the 0th), the start time of the
# machine must be greater than the previous start + duration
for j in range(jobs):  # for each job
    for m_idx in range(1, len(machine_sequence[j])):  # for each machine in job's seq, except 0
        # convenience for bookkeeping...  
        curr_machine = machine_sequence[j][m_idx]
        prior_machine = machine_sequence[j][m_idx - 1]

        # so,
        schedule += x[j, curr_machine] >= x[j, prior_machine] + times[j][prior_machine]

####### single-use constraint (jobs can't be on same machine at same time) #######
for j, j_prime, m in jjm:
    # if y, job j precedes j_prime, if not, use big M
    schedule += x[j, m] + times[j][m] <= x[j_prime, m] + (1-y[j, j_prime, m])*M

    # one or the other case below must be true...
    # aside:  this is lazy as it will produce duplicates,
    #         but the solver will remove them
    schedule += y[j, j_prime, m] + y[j_prime, j, m] == 1

####### constraint to capture the longest makespan #######
schedule += c  # put the obj into model
for j, m in valid_starts:  # for every job started on every machine...
    schedule += c >= x[j, m] + times[j][m]  # capture the latest finish time
#print(schedule)

status = schedule.solve()

print(f"status: {schedule.status}, {LpStatus[schedule.status]}")
print("Completion time: ", schedule.objective.value())

for j, m in valid_starts:
    if x[j, m].varValue >= 0:
        print("job %d starts on machine %d at time %g" % (j, m, x[j, m].varValue))
```

#### Yields:

```
status: 1, Optimal
Completion time:  11.0
job 0 starts on machine 0 at time 0
job 0 starts on machine 2 at time 2
job 1 starts on machine 1 at time 0
job 1 starts on machine 2 at time 5
job 1 starts on machine 0 at time 10
```

Flow.  Using 1-index jobs...  sorry for flip-flop

[image]

Comment: I spent some hours with the new indexing, which makes more intuitive sense, but not sure how I can connect them back to original formulation (specifically the constraints) which includes variables for times and machines. If you could elaborate on how to incorporate j-m pairs for these particular constraints that'd be really helpful.

Comment: I'll give it a look.  Like I said above, I'm not sure if your orig formulation was correct.  It did not produce answer for me, even when I put in a number...  I think I can at least gin up an example, but I haven't worked w/ makespan in a bit.

Comment: Awesome! If it helps, I missed adding the objective function to the schedule model above (schedule += c). Complete code is now updated above. It should work as long as there are no None types for the variable machines.

Comment: added a bit more...

Comment: Thanks, that first constraint was really helpful. I used it to make updates to the last 2 constraints below, but not sure if I carried through correctly using your dictionary idea. Would be awesome if you could take a look. I defined that y binary variable above too.

Comment: Updated w/ a full model

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240211/discussion-between-gabe-verzino-and-airsquid).

Comment: Weird... on the output, Job 1 takes 5 hours long and starts on machine 0, but the optimal makespan is 11 hours. How can that be?

Comment: (speaking in 0-index)...  Job 0 and 1 both start at t=0 on machines 0, 1 respectively.  Job 0 finishes at t=2 and moves on to machine 2 until time 5, which blocks (for 1 time unit) Job 1 from starting on machine 2 after it is ready to start... the is the fastest flow.

Comment: I must be missing something. Using 0-index, Job 1 has times 1, 4, 5 right? So if Job 1 starts on machine 1 at t=0 and runs 1 unit to t=1, then starts on machine 2 at t=5, and runs 4 units to t=9. Then starts on machine 0 at t=10 and runs 5 units to t=15. How is optimal flow 11?

Comment: Thanks for illustration... you'd think that Job 2 in machine order 1, 2, 0... that the corresponding time durations would be 1, 4, 5... instead (as shown) it's 4, 5, 1. Must've swapped j, m somewhere I bet... Added picture to my answer below

Comment: Figured it out, need to make sure valid_starts are sorted properly... valid_starts.sort()... this ensure correct times (durations) align with machines and jobs

Comment: The order of the tuples in `valid_starts` should not matter at all.  Right now, the `times` matrix is indexed by [job, machine #] *not* [job, task sequence #].  That should be intuitive from the fact that `times` has `None` entry for job 0, machine 1.  It would be a PITA to do it the other way, because then you would have to shuffle things around there if you changed task sequences....this way it is static.  Of course, the more clear alternative would be  to hold the input data in dictionaries instead of matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Some additional constraints using j,m pairs.

```
# constraint 2: makespan
for j in range(jobs):
    for m_idx in range(1, len(machine_sequence[j])): 
        curr_machine = machine_sequence[j][m_idx]
        prior_machine = machine_sequence[j][m_idx - 1]
        
        schedule += c - x[j, prior_machine] >= times[j][prior_machine]

# constraint 3: only 1 job processing at a given time in a given machine
for j in range(jobs):
    for m_idx in range(1, len(machine_sequence[j])): 
        curr_machine = machine_sequence[j][m_idx]
        prior_machine = machine_sequence[j][m_idx - 1]
        for k in range(jobs):
            if j != k:
                schedule += x[j, prior_machine] - x[k, prior_machine] >= times[k][prior_machine] - M*(1-y[j][k][m_idx])
                schedule += x[k, prior_machine] - x[j, prior_machine] >= times[j][prior_machine] - M*(y[j][k][m_idx])
```

[image]